# Using static and dynamic library packages with Conan and MSVC++

Tags: visual-c++, shared-libraries, conan

I have an MSVS solution with two projects: DLL one generates `library.lib` and `library.dll`, static library one generates `library_st.lib`. `conanfile.py` packages those three objects into package.

I have another MSVS solution (`conanfile.txt` only) which `[requires]` first project. Conan generates .props file which links to `library.lib`, and I can't find a way to link to `library_st.lib` with it.

I tried passing `shared=False` to a library and changing its `package()` method to save only static library. I don't know how to check the exact binary package files but my solution still tries to link to 'library.lib' after that change.

I guess my question is two-part:

1. How to create dynamic and static library with Conan and MSVS 2017?
2. How to choose which library I link to when package has several `.lib` files in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to create dynamic and static library with Conan and MSVS 2017?

If you are using CMake + MSVC, you just need to add the [option](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#options) *shared*. [CMake helper](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html#cmake-reference) will translate that option to *BUILD_SHARED_LIBS* definition when configuring your project.

However, if you are using only Visual Studio, it depends how your project is configured. Conan [MSBuild](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/visual_studio.html#msbuild) is able to select what you want, including target, architecture and build type. You could use different targets, one for each configuration.

> How to choose which library I link to when package has several .lib files in it?

By options. When creating a package, Conan will export all library names that you want by *self.cpp_info.libs*. You can call *tools.collect_libs(self)*, which will list all libraries in the package folder or, you can list what you want e.g. [library_st, library]. If you need to choose which library you want to link, you should need to add an option with the library to be listed, otherwise you will need to ignore CONAN_PKG:: or CONAN_LIBS when linking:

```
from conans import Conanfile, MSBuild

class ExampleConan(Conanfile):
    name = "example"
    version = "0.1.0"
    settings = "os", "arch", "build_type", "compiler"
    options = {"shared": [True, False], "st": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False, "st": False}
    exports = "*"
    _msvc_archs = {"x86": "x86", "x86_64": "x64"}

    def build(self):
        msbuild = MSBuild(self)
        msbuild.build("Example.sln", platforms=self._msvc_archs)

    def package(self):
        library_folder = os.path.join(self._msvc_archs[self.settings.arch.value], self.settings.build_type.value)
        self.copy("*.lib", src=library_folder, dst="lib")
        if self.options.shared:
            self.copy("*.dll", src=library_folder, dst="bin")

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["library_st"] if self.options.st else ["library"]
```

IMO you are trying to build two projects in the same package, which sounds wrong. I would say you should create separated packages for each one. You could create one individual recipe for each project. You should remember that each option will introduce a new point for a package ID.